# Connecting Unity Firebase SDK to Local Firebase Auth Emulator

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I'm currently working on a Unity project and using Firebase for authentication. I would like to test the authentication functionality using the local Firebase Auth emulator. However, I'm having trouble connecting the Unity Firebase SDK to the local emulator.

I've followed the Firebase documentation and have successfully set up the local Firebase emulator suite, including the Auth emulator. I can test the authentication flows using the Firebase CLI commands and the Firebase web SDK.

However, I'm not sure how to configure the Unity Firebase SDK to connect to the local Firebase Auth emulator. I've searched for relevant documentation and examples but haven't found any specific instructions for Unity.

Has anyone successfully connected the Unity Firebase SDK to the local Firebase Auth emulator? If so, could you please provide guidance on how to configure the Unity Firebase SDK to connect to the local emulator?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried looking for examples but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Firebase Unity SDK doesn't support emulators for Firebase Authentication. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth) for your reference.

I found an existing [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/1229) filed on Firebase Unity quickstart project. You may also try to file another feature request via [Firebase support portal](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) or on [Firebase Unity SDK GitHub repository](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/new/choose).

Comment: this is really unfortunate, it forces you to the blaze plan, since you can't test for example function like this on emulator -> export const beforeLogin = functions.auth.user().beforeSignIn((user)=>{